# Retrieving original data from PyTorch nn.Embedding

Tags: pytorch, embedding

I'm passing a dataframe with 5 categories (ex. car, bus, ...) into `nn.Embedding`.

When I do `embedding.parameters()`, I can see that there are 5tensors but how do I know which index corresponds to the original input (ex. car, bus, ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't as tensors are unnamed (only dimensions can be named, see [PyTorch's Named Tensors](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/named_tensor.html)).
You have to keep the names in separate data container, for example (`4` categories here):

```
import pandas as pd
import torch

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "bus": [1.0, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "car": [6.0, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        "bike": [11.0, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        "train": [16.0, 17, 18, 19, 20],
    }
)

df_data = df.to_numpy().T
df_names = list(df)

embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(df_data.shape[0], df_data.shape[1])
embedding.weight.data = torch.from_numpy(df_data)
```

Now you can simply use it with any index you want:

```
index = 1
embedding(torch.tensor(index)), df_names[index]
```

This would give you `(tensor[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], "car")` so the data and respective column name.

Comment: My data column looks more like this: "type": ["car", "bus", "bike", "train"]. what happens in this case?

Comment: @AndreaEunbeeJang Those are column names?

Comment: oh actually, nvm! I understand what you did there. Thank you!!!